# Add more cores to the parallel running processes in GNU parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I'm using GNU parallel to run several jobs in parallel.

I was wondering whether GNU parallel includes a command which allows to add n more cores to the processes that are already running in parallel.

Do you have some suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use `-j file` you can change the content of `file`. From `man parallel`:

> --jobs procfile
>
> -j procfile
>
> --max-procs procfile
>
> -P procfile
>
> Read parameter from file. Use the content of procfile as parameter for -j. E.g. procfile could contain the string 100% or +2 or 10. If procfile is changed when a job completes, procfile is read again and the new number of jobs is computed. If the number is lower than before, running jobs will be allowed to finish but new jobs will not be started until the wanted number of jobs has been reached. This makes it possible to change the number of simultaneous running jobs while GNU parallel is running.

Comment: Ok, this is interesting. Currently I have 5 processes running so according to what you said I should modify the procfile by writing for instance +2 (if I want add 2 more cores). However I don't know what is and where to find the procfile.

Comment: You can only do it if it was started with a proc file: `parallel --jobs myprocfile ...`. Here you can then alter myprocfile. If you did not start GNU Parallel with that, you cannot change it.

Comment: Thank you! I will run the analyses with this option.

Comment: I have another "naive" question that I would ask as comment. I run parallel by using the following command: nohup ls *.R | time parallel -j4 R CMD BATCH &, and because I would like to do what you suggested with procfile I would like to stop parallel running and re-start a new one. How do I do?

Comment: `echo 4 > myprocfile ; nohup time parallel -j myprocfile R CMD BATCH ::: *.R` or if screen is available `screen parallel -j myprocfile R CMD BATCH ::: *.R` CTRL-A d.